# Spring MVC form handling form multiple pojos

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need help understanding some form handling. Suppose I have two pojo like below.

**First:**

```
public class Loginfo {
   private String username;
   private String password;

   // setters and getters ... 
}
```

**Second:**

```
pubic class PersonalInfo {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private Loginfo loginfo;

    // setters and getters... 
}
```

And lastly I have a form with the fields: `username`, `password`, `name`, `age`.

How do I handle this form? What should the controller code look like?

Comment: Reading spring doc or google that will give you an answer pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a JSON converter in your application. You can use Jackson for this purpose. You will need the Jackson core,databind and annotation jars/dependencies for this. Make sure all three jars/dependencies are of same version.

Add below to dispatcher-servlet:

```
<beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>
```

The above code will directly convert objects to JSON and vice versa whenever an http request comes in to the controller.

The code in controller would look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/serviceName", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody void service(@RequestBody PersonalInfo personalInfo){
}
```

Make sure the name of the var you post is personalInfo.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer is right but the easiest way to do this is just name your form field name like your pojo variable name for example

```
<input type="text" name="loginfo.username" />
```

and of your right the following code in controller then that should be work..

```
@RequestMapping(value="yourMapping",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String yourMethodName(PersonalInfo info){
    return "yourMpaaing";
}
```

Comment: Your question is about multiple objects, your answer about a single one. One of them has to be changed to make sense.